# Is MySQL enum performance slower than INT?

Tags: mysql, enums

Is it better to have a field `status enum('active', 'hidden', 'deleted')` OR `status tinyint(3)` with a lookup table? Assume that status can take only one value at a time.

In particular, I am interested in knowing if operations on `enum` are significantly slower than or as fast as operations on `int`?

There is [a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343450/mysql-enum-confusion) but:

1. It does not discuss performance at all;
2. There is very little explanation on **why** one approach is better than the other.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is already discussed on popular http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com, check out this post:

- [Enum Fields VS Varchar VS Int + Joined table: What is Faster?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/)

Comment: I'm glad the link still works. A brief summary would warrant an upvote. :)

Comment: TLDR or if the link is down: A test is done to show that there is no significant difference, with ENUM being very slightly faster than VARCHAR.